# Authentication to SharePoint online with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext works in VS, fails in Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, sharepoint

I have some code to create a SharePoint Online Modern Page which works fine from VS, tested with three different SharePoint accounts. The same code running on an Azure function works with only one of the three accounts. For the accounts that do not work, I get the message:
The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
All three accounts have the same permissions in SharePoint and like I say, all work fine from VS.
Any thoughts on why this works from VS and not Azure? I'm using .Net Framework as already discovered that authentication does not appear to work correctly in .Net Core.

```
        private static ClientContext GetClientContext(string siteUrl, string userAccount, string userPassword)
    {

        ClientContext ccNew = new ClientContext(siteUrl); //"https://nelsoncity.sharepoint.com/sites/IwiEngagement/");
        SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
        Array.ForEach(userPassword.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
        ccNew.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userAccount, sec_pass);

        return ccNew;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@PDTech

```
The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
```

This error occurs - because of possibility of the having the MFA(Multifactor Authentication) enabled for these accounts outside the Organisation network / Domain network.

A quick test for this would be :

Take a machine outside the domain network, try logging in using the same credentials & see whether you encountering any additional steps for log-in ( like a phone call, text , authenticator etc)

The reason why i suspect MFA is enabled at network level - because the same works with a local environment.

For details about the configuration of MFA

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings#mfa-service-settings

If possible, you could exempt these accounts from the MFA or add the Azure Functions IP as trusted IP.

Comment: @PDtech - did the above solution help or do you have any further queries ?